# Improving Elisp Conditional expression

Tags: elisp

The elisp code for the below pseudo code

```
if "the emacs version is less than 23.1.x"
do
  something
else
  something-else
```

is written as

```
(if (or (< emacs-major-version 23)
        (and (= emacs-major-version 23)
             (<= emacs-minor-version 1)))
    (setq color-theme-is-global t)
  (color-theme-initialize))
```

How to optimize the above code, so that the "emacs-major-version" is not referenced twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for that, there's `version<=` and `emacs-version`

```
(if (version<= emacs-version "23.1")
    (setq color-theme-is-global t)
  (color-theme-initialize))
```

Comment: (version) fn returns a string describing the version of Emacs. Could you please clarify how does this comparision b/w string and number works.

Comment: It's `emacs-version` not `(emacs-version)`. For the workings of `version<=` See it's docstring, `C-h f version<=`.